# Is it ok to use API instead of SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I like fast code execution (because of that I switched from Python to Go) and I do not like dependencies. Amazon recommends using SDK for simpler authentication (but in Lambda I can get tokens from IAM from environment variables) and because of built into SDK retry on errors (few lines of code, as I think). Yes it is faster to write my code using SDK, but what additional caveats about using pure HTTP API instead of SDK? Am I too crazy about milliseconds? Such optimizations worth it?

Comment: Unless your app is "mission critical" (very few fall into this category), I wouldn't go for such optimization because, you will be spending lot of time writing code someone already did in form of SDK. Remember, though you got REST API access, you still need to parse this and covert into your objects, you may be able to save VERY LITTLE on compute (unless you are master programmer).

Comment: To answer your other question, can we use REST API instead of SDK, yes and I am 95% confident that SDK internally does the REST call for us. Reviewing some of the open source SDK could reveal these details.

Comment: There's no requirement to use an AWS SDK. Everything's available via underlying API. Having said that, you might want to do some work to validate the advantages that you think you will get from bypassing the SDK.

Comment: As an employer I would question your allocation of time/effort. The SDKs are maintained by AWS, whereas your code would need to be maintained internally, probably for years after you have left the company. Given that most of the time is spent waiting for a network response, the tiny potential speed improvement would be negligible.

Comment: It's easy enough to try it and see what you find.  I recently wrote my own implementation of `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` that runs 9x faster than aws-cli on the same task. I expect that the cli may be an outlier, but there are probably opportunities for performance gains elsewhere.  You will definitely gain improved troubleshooting skills that come in handy when the SDK's behavior perplexes you, by learning the underlying APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stated focus on performance belies real trade-offs.

Consider that someone will have to maintain your code -- if you use an API, the test area is small, but AWS APIs <strike>might change or be deprecated</strike>; if you use an SDK, next programmer will plug in new SDK version and hope that it works, but if it doesn't they'd be bogged down by sheer weight of the SDK, for example, there are known diamond dependency incompatibilities with AWS SDKs specifically (app → dep → subdep@v2; app → SDK → subdep@v1).

Edit: AWS famously keeps their APIs around for a good decade and sometimes two decades. SDKs are updated more frequently. Some other vendors update their APIs at much faster cadence. Then again, some other vendors use SDKs as the way to plug holes in the existing APIs. In short, best choice depends on the target service.

Likewise, imagine someone needs to do a security review of this app, or to introduce something not yet covered by SDK (let's imagine propagating accounting group from caller role to underlying storage).

I don't think there is a clear answer.

Here are my **suggestions**:

- keep it consistent -- either API or SDK (within given app, for given service)
- consider the bigger picture (how many apps do you plan to write?)
- don't be afraid to switch to the other approach later

I've had to decide on something similar **in the past**, with Docker (much nicer APIs and SDKs/libs). Here's how it played out:

For testing, we ended up using beta version of Docker Python bindings: prod version was not enough, and bindings (your SDK) were overall pretty good and clear.

For log scraping, I used HTTP calls (your API), "because performance", in reality comparative mental load using API vs SDK, and because bindings (SDK) did not support asyncio.

Answer (score 3):

Anything you do with AWS is the result of an API call, whether executed by CLI, Web console, or SDK.

The SDKs make it easier to interact with those APIs.  While you may be able to come up with some minor improvements for some calls, overall you will spend a lot of time doing it to very little benefit.

Comment: Not so minor: my colleagues improved throughput by 2x at https://github.com/HENNGE/aiodynamo compared to AWS SDK.